# function to get nth letter from a string outputs number 1

Tags: python

when I try to get second character of string "hello" to get letter e it prints "1" for some reason

```
string = "hello"
print_string = string[2]

print(print_string)
```

I want to get the letter e or nth letter but I just get number 1

Comment: are you sure the `1` is not the letter `l`? that would make sense, since Python uses zero-indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not printing a number `1`; it is printing a lowercase letter "L", which is the third letter in the world `"hello"`.  Remember that Python is zero-indexed, so the first letter will be at index `0`, and the second letter at index `1`.  Try:

```py
string = "hello"
print_string = string[1]

print(print_string)
```

Answer (score 1):

python is index-based, counting begins with zero:

string = "hello"

```
h e l l o\
0 1 2 3 4
```

use:

```
print(string[0])
```

to access "h"

or:

```
print(string[4])
```

to access "o"

it's not necessary to use an additional variable "print_string" in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way of looking at it:

```
>>> for index, letter in enumerate("hello"):
...     print (f'index={index} letter={letter}')       
... 
index=0 letter='h'
index=1 letter='e'
index=2 letter='l'
index=3 letter='l'
index=4 letter='o'
```